# How can I show an image using the ImageView component in javafx and fxml?

Tags: java, imageview, fxml

I suppose it's a very simple thing but I just can't get behind it.
All I want is to show an image over an ImageView linked to fxml.
Here is my code:

```
package application;

import java.io.File;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class Main extends Application
{
    @FXML
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {
        try 
        {
        AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");

        File file = new File("src/Box13.jpg");
        Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
        imageView = new ImageView(image);

        //root.getChildren().add(imageView);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

And my fxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="316.0" prefWidth="321.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"     xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="application.SampleController">
  <children>
    <ImageView fx:id="imageView" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="61.0" layoutY="83.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" >

    </ImageView>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

There should be no problem with the file linking as it works fine when I include the outcommented line. This would be the way it's done in java only but I want to use fxml here as I am using fxml for all other components but it just doesn't work for the ImageView and I don't know why. I have also tried to create a new controller class and link the ImageView there but that neither works. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 24):

If you want to use FXML, you should separate the controller (like you were doing with the SampleController). Then your `fx:controller` in your FXML should point to that.

Probably you are missing the `initialize` method in your controller, which is part of the `Initializable` interface. This method is called after the FXML is loaded, so I recommend you to set your image there.

Your `SampleController` class must be something like this:

```
public class SampleController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        File file = new File("src/Box13.jpg");
        Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
        imageView.setImage(image);
    }
}
```

I tested here and it's working.

Comment: `imageView` is not initialized at this stage. It will throw exception.

Comment: @FaizanMubasher When loading this controller via the FXML Loader, the `initialize` method will be automatically called only after all JavaFX components are initialized, therefore it will NOT throw an exception.

Answer (score 16):

You don't need an initializer, unless you're dynamically loading a different image each time. I think doing as much as possible in fxml is more organized. Here is an fxml file that will do what you need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.co/fxml/1"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2"
    fx:controller="application.SampleController"
    prefHeight="316.0"
    prefWidth="321.0"
    >
    <children>
        <ImageView
                fx:id="imageView"
                fitHeight="150.0"
                fitWidth="200.0"
                layoutX="61.0"
                layoutY="83.0"
                pickOnBounds="true"
                preserveRatio="true"
            >
            <image>
                <Image
                    url="src/Box13.jpg"
                    backgroundLoading="true"
                    />
            </image>
        </ImageView>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Specifying the backgroundLoading property in the Image tag is optional, it defaults to false. It's best to set backgroundLoading true when it takes a moment or longer to load the image, that way a placeholder will be used until the image loads, and the program wont freeze while loading.

Answer (score 6):

The Code part :

```
Image imProfile = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/img/profile128.png"));

ImageView profileImage=new ImageView(imProfile);
```

in a javafx maven:

[image]

Comment: This code is working, thank you. Another answer is working only if I not compile it, after I compile to JAR, the image not show.

Answer (score 2):

```
@FXML
ImageView image;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
  image.setImage(new Image ("/about.jpg"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find below example to load image using JavaFX.

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.image.Image;
    import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class LoadImage extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Load Image");

    StackPane sp = new StackPane();
    Image img = new Image("javafx.jpg");
    ImageView imgView = new ImageView(img);
    sp.getChildren().add(imgView);

    //Adding HBox to the scene
    Scene scene = new Scene(sp);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    }

  }
```

Create one source folder with name Image in your project and add your image to that folder otherwise you can directly load image from external URL like following.

Image img = new Image("http://mikecann.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/javafx_logo_color_1.jpg");

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to put the image to the resources, than you can use it like this:

```
imageView = new ImageView("/gui.img/img.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

src/sample/images/shopp.png

```java
Parent root =new StackPane();
ImageView ımageView=new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/shopp.png")));
((StackPane) root).getChildren().add(ımageView);
```